# Managed Package in Scratch Org

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

Can anyone confirm if we can create managed packages in Scratch org. Of so, can please share the relevant documentation.

Comment: No, must be on developer org, are you working for an isv?

Comment: No.. but I have to hide my classes and other piece source code... Dev Org I knew, but I can't do in that because I don't have it corresponding to prod. And I don't want to develop in any org which don't have association to my prod org, as it needs to have my prod customizations. Hope you understand the concern...

Comment: How about 2nd generation managed Package ?

Comment: This seems like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you do not work for an ISV and are building code to be deploying to a single prod environment, why do you need a managed package to provide IP protection?

Comment: Hi David, so there are multiple stakeholders for Dev... Hence, code abstraction is being emphasized. Little confused on the approach I should be using

Answer (score 0):

Managed packages are not a tool for code modularization and abstraction within a single production org. Managed packages are intended for ISVs to deliver their products to Salesforce customers, and come with an extensive list of benefits (including IP protection) and restrictions.

It is unclear exactly what you're being asked to do here. It may be as little as complying with enterprise design patterns that utilize separation of concerns and a layered architecture. Or, it may be that your organization plans to utilize the [Package Development Model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_dev_model) with Unlocked Packages, which you *do* build in a source-focused, scratch org-based development model.

You should work with your technical lead or architect to understand exactly what code architecture is being prescribed.